# Just updated the Embedly plugin and get this error.

Tags: wordpress, embedly

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in D:\Hosting\2772443\html\wp-content\plugins\embedly\embedly.php on line 535

Can not activate Fatal Error.  Is Embedly aware?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a version issue with PHP. A new version of the Embedly plugin will be available later today.